# Trying to install vendors in Centos 6 with icu 4.2.1 installed

Tags: symfony

Since Im getting error messages about the icu version When running `php composer.phar install`, I have added this line below as said [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html#installation):

```
"symfony/icu": "1.1.*",
```

So my composer.json is like this:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/icu": "1.1.*",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "ziiweb/frontendbundle": "@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "dev-master",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

But after installing again, I get this errors:

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package symfony/icu could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.   Problem 2
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.3.x-dev].
    - symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.3.x-dev requires symfony/icu 1.1.* -> no matching package found.   Problem 3
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony v2.3.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.3.8].
    - symfony/symfony v2.3.8 requires symfony/icu ~1.0 -> no matching package found.   Problem 4
    - symfony/symfony v2.3.8 requires symfony/icu ~1.0 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/media-bundle 2.2.x-dev requires symfony/symfony ~2.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.3.8].
    - Installation request for sonata-project/media-bundle 2.2.x-dev -> satisfiable by sonata-project/media-bundle[2.2.x-dev].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting    see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details
```

.

Answer (score 0):

it is `"symfony/Icu"` with capital letter

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to download the INTL extension of PHP.Go to http://pecl.php.net/get/intl-3.0.0.tgz
2. Tar that file, and compile it with the following commands.
   tar zxvf intl-3.0.0.tgz
   cd intl-3.0.0
   /usr/bin/phpize
   ./configure --with-php-config=[YOUR OWN INSTALLED PHP DIRECTORY]/bin/php-config
3. Update your php.ini.
   extension=intl.so
4. Restart your php server
   By the way, if the problem still shows up after you finish above procedures, please check if you install that extension for PHP CLI. You know there are different php.ini files for PHP and PHP CLI sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was deleting the composer.lock file, then do a composer install.

edit:  I also deleted the vendor directory